# How to aggregate AWS SQS ApproximateNumberOfMessages

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-lambda

Given X number of SQS queues, how can I aggregate the ApproximateNumberOfMessages into one CloudWatch Metric?

I would like to have an auto-scaling group scale based on how many messages there are in the queues. Using multiple CloudWatch Alarms (one for each queue) causes issues as one queue will be empty while the others are "full".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way that I achieved this is by using AWS Lambda with Node.js. I added a CloudWatch Event trigger to run the lambda function every minute. This queries the sqs queues then creates a custom CloudWatch Metric which you can then use for the auto-scaling group to scale.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sqs = new AWS.SQS();
var cloudWatch = new AWS.CloudWatch();

var queueUrls = ['https://sqs.REGION.amazonaws.com/ACCOUNT-NUMBER/queueUrl1','https://sqs.REGION.amazonaws.com/ACCOUNT-NUMBER/queueUrl2'];

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var fn = function (url) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var sqsParams = {
                AttributeNames: ['ApproximateNumberOfMessages'],
                QueueUrl: url
            };

            sqs.getQueueAttributes(sqsParams, function(err,data){
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err,err.stack);
                    context.fail(err);
                }
                else
                {
                    resolve({name: url.split('/').pop(), messageCount: parseInt(data.Attributes.ApproximateNumberOfMessages)});
                }
            }); 
        });
    };

    var actions = queueUrls.map(fn);
    Promise.all(actions).then(function(queues) {
        var messageCount = queues.map(function(m){return m.messageCount;});
        var queueNames = queues.map(function(n){return n.name;}).join();

        var metricParams = {
            MetricData:[{
                MetricName: 'ApproximateNumberOfMessages',
                Dimensions:[{
                    Name: 'QueueName',
                    Value: queueNames
                }],
                Unit: 'Count',
                StatisticValues: {
                    Maximum: Math.max.apply(Math, messageCount),
                    Minimum: Math.min.apply(Math, messageCount),
                    SampleCount: queues.length,
                    Sum: messageCount.reduce((pv, cv) => pv+cv, 0)
                }
            }],
            Namespace: 'AWS/SQS'
        };
        cloudWatch.putMetricData(metricParams, function(err, metricData){
            if(err) console.log(err,err.stack);
            else console.log(metricData);
        });
    });
};
```

<strike>This code can obviously be optimized to handle more than 2 queues and can probably benefit from async waterfall.</strike>

EDIT: Updated to use promises.

EDIT2: Concatenate queue names for CloudWatch Metric